# If I cast Green-Flame Blade but my attack misses, and I use an extra action from Haste to attack again, does GFB's effect apply if that attack hits?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, actions, cantrips

Let us assume that my wizard has the *Haste* spell cast on him, granting him an additional action on each turn. He casts *Green-Flame Blade* as his first action, attacking as part of the spell, but that attack misses.

If my wizard uses his additional action from *haste* to make another melee weapon attack, and it hits, does the effect of *Green-Flame Blade* trigger then?
Or is the magic spent with the first missed attack?

I know the spell's duration is Instantaneous, but the trigger is a successful attack. It makes sense to me that another attack in the same round could possibly trigger it if the first misses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### *Green-Flame Blade* only "triggers" if using the action to cast the spell

The [*Green-Flame Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) cantrip has a casting time of 1 action, and its description says (TCoE, p. 107; SCAG, p. 142):

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell's casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you. On a hit, the target suffers the weapon attack's normal effects, and you can cause green fire to leap from the target to a different creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of it. The second creature takes fire damage equal to your spellcasting ability modifier.

Casting the spell is the action that lets you make a melee attack, not the other way around.

If you miss, then it misses, and that's the end of the action, just like if you were using *Fire Bolt*.

Now, if you had something silly like Action Surge and the Quickened Spell Metamagic, you could use action 1 to cast *Green-Flame Blade*, use Action Surge and use action 2 to cast *Green-Flame Blade*, then use Quickened Spell to use a bonus action to cast *Green-Flame Blade* – but that's hardly optimal.

---

**A note about *Haste*:** The [*Haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell is limited in which actions can be performed with the additional action it grants you:

> That [additional] action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

Comment: @goodguy5 - I understand the limitations of Haste, that is why I did not mention casting GFB a second time.  I just had it in my head that the weapon held the charge - now I see that is not the case, it is just another part of the same action - sort of like a very specific somatic gesture.  Just wishful thinking on my part, I guess. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Splitter I suspected as much, I just wanted to make sure it was clear for anyone reading.

Comment: It is *always* a good idea to leave a reminder about the limitations of the extra action given by *haste*.

Answer (score 13):

### The *green-flame blade* spell cannot activate after missing with its attack

#### The spell's duration is "Instantaneous"

Firstly, the duration of [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) is "[instantaneous](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Instantaneous)". What this means is that

> The spell harms, heals, creates, or alters a creature or an object in a way that can't be dispelled, because its magic exists only for an instant."

Because of this, it would at least be *unusual* if the spell had an effect after it was cast (though some instantaneous spells *do* have lasting effects (such as *feeblemind*) so this isn't conclusive evidence on its own).

---

#### The spell does *not* indicate that it persists

We can compare the wording of *green-flame blade* to something like [*branding smite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/branding-smite):

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell's casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you. On a hit [...]

> The next time you hit a creature with a weapon attack before this spell ends [...]

There are a few things to note here. First, *branding smite* has a duration of 1 minute and requires concentration, while *green-flame blade* does not. This indicates that the former can last after its initial casting while the latter cannot.

Second, *branding smite* occurs "the *next* time you hit a creature" whereas *green-flame blade* occurs on a hit with the attack that is made *as part of the spell's casting*. If it were intended to apply to attacks other than the one made *when casting the spell*, the spell would mention this fact similar to how *branding smite* does.

---

Lacking any text to support that *green-flame blade* has a lasting duration and lacking any text to support that it can activate on an attack *besides* the one made as part of the spell, we conclude that *green-flame blade* **cannot** activate with the attack from the *haste* spell.

Answer (score 7):

### The effect of *Green-Flame Blade* does not trigger again

The description of *Green-Flame Blade* says, in part (SCAG, p. 142; emphasis added):

> **As part of the action used to cast this spell**, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack's normal effects, and green fire leaps [...]

The effects described are related to the attack that is part of the action casting the spell.

Additional attacks, whether from *Haste*, or because you are multiclassed with a fighter that has Action Surge or Extra Attack, or any other feature giving you additional attacks, are not part of the action of casting the spell.

Comment: Note: The description of [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) (and the other cantrips in SCAG) was slightly changed in 2020 as of the release of *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, and [SCAG received an errata accordingly](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf). The first sentence now simply reads: "You brandish the weapon used in the spell’s casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you." Your answer's overall claim is right, but the part of the quote you bolded no longer appears in the description.