# Will green-flame blade damage bonus apply to multiple attacks made in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, attack, cantrips

One can only cast 1 cantrip per turn (at least, as a warlock). But does the bonus damage rolled by Green-Flame Blade apply to multiple attacks, such as those coming from Improved Pact Weapon?

Comment: Related: [If your fighter casts Green-Flame Blade or Booming Blade, do you still get extra Attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114006/if-your-fighter-casts-green-flame-blade-or-booming-blade-do-you-still-get-extra)

Comment: Related: "[Does Green Flame Blade and Sweeping Attack combo cause the bonus effect of GFB to hit again?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172357)" and "[If I cast Green-Flame Blade but my attack misses, and I use an extra action from Haste to attack again, does GFB's effect apply if that attack hits?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/196126)"

Comment: Improved Pact Weapon doesn't seem to do anything relating to multiple attacks, where you thinking of Thirsting Weapon perchance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It will only apply damage once

Green-Flame Blade says:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell's casting and make **a melee attack** with it against one crea­ture within 5 feet of you. **On a hit,** *(damage effects are described)*

The spell allows you to take only **a melee attack**, not on a full attack action, or multiple attacks, and the extra damage and effects apply to **a hit with that attack**.

Making that melee attack is part of the spell's effect. Additional attacks, even if you can take them separately, are not part of its effect, and do not benefit from its additional damage.

Comment: I think you are saying that when you cast green flame blade you get a single strike, empowered with the green flame magic, and that if you have a way of making 2 attacks (such as extra attack, or something from a pact) you can still only take one, but I don't think it is as clear in this answer as it could be. I read this as saying the first attack benefits from green flame blade, but the other attacks can still be taken, and I don't think that is what you are trying to say.

Comment: @SeriousBri Thank you, yes, that is what I mean. I rephrased it to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

When you use GFB, you are taking the cast a spell action.  As such, any ability that requires you use the Attack action (like extra attack) can't be used.  If you cast GFB you only get a single melee attack as a part of that action.

You could get additional attacks during the same turn if you quicken GFB, but the single melee attack you take and the resulting damage are both part of the spell, the cantrip would have no effect on any other actions you might take.